# Laravel: how to set string as optional in route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-route

in `web.php` I have:

```
Route::get('car/id/{id}/color/{color?}', 'carController@getCar);
```

But I want the whole part of `/color/{color?}` to be optional not just the color parameter `/{color?}`, would you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Route::get('search/{query?}', 'YourController@method')->where('query','.+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Better To Used Query String Parameter here(now whole part should be optional by default)...

```
Route::get('car', 'carController@getCar);
```

example :

```
car?id=1&color=red
car?id=2
car
```

in Controller `getCar` Method

```
getCart() {
    $id = request()->get('id');
    $color = request()->get('color');
}
```